# Google Analytics API authentication failure using JWT

Tags: python, oauth, jwt, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I want to connect to Google Analytics Reporting API to fetch data, For which I have been provided with details of the service account in JSON format which contains details like (type, project_id, client_email, client_id, private_key,client_x509_cert_url, auth_provider_x509_cert_url)

Using this JSON file I am able to connect and fetch required report data via Python code [Reporting API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py). However, due to business requirements, I have to establish the connection using HTTP Rest API.

So based on the details of the same service account I am trying to authenticate using JWT by referring to Google Docs [Addendum: Service account authorization without OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth) so that once I get the signature I can use that as a static token and make next API call to get report data `https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet` and passing Request Body

But while testing in https://jwt.io/ & also in https://irrte.ch/jwt-js-decode/index.html signature creation is failing with an Invalid Signature error.

Can someone please help to understand what am I missing here?

```
Header

{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "<service account's private key ID>"
}

Payload

{
   
  "iss": "<service account's email address i.e. client_email>",
  "sub": "<service account's email address i.e. client_email>",
  "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "iat": <UTC Unix Epoch Start Time>,
  "exp": <UTC Unix Epoch End Time>

}

And then pasted X.509 PUBLIC CERTIFICATE generated for the service account and in Private key pasted Private key again which is from JSON file of service account



-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIrrhherhehrgssreheheherhehehehrhrdsfsfzcsvsvsvscssvsrjnfvdsfsscscscshgeferttyyuuuuuuuuuuudDxE/Q\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nLDSVSVSCSYUNJKOLPDFSSSFSFSFSSFSFSFSFSFSFSSFSFSFSFSFSFSFSSSSSSSSSGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUM=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

PS: I have tried to test with \n without \n as well as with prefixes BEGIN, END and without it still have the same result.

Comment: I will just say that I have tried to code service account authorization myself with out the client libraries on and off for the last ten years.  I have never been able to do it.   If you really want to do this.  Dig around in the code for the google api python client library maybe you can rip enough code out to do it yourself.   Otherwise save yourself some grief and just use the client library.   If you get it to work I would love to see the code.